# data transmitted in oracle TNS protocol in wireshark

Tags: networking, protocols, tns

There is a protocol in Wireshark protocols list that I don't understand it.

What is TNS protocol?

What kind of data transmitted with it?

How its header like?

What it's application?

Answer (score 1):

Transparent Network Substrate (TNS), a proprietary Oracle protocol.
It is used to communicate between an SQL client( or APP) and an Oracle server.

As it is proprietary, the header information is mostly based on individual analysis on the specific version deployed(server and client)